# jtable de internal frame a jtable de un jframe

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito saber como puedo hacer que los datos de un `jtable` de un *internal frame*, pasen a otro `jtable` que esta en un `jframe` en *java netbeans*, estoy realizando un proyecto en este lenguaje y soy nuevo en esto.

Esto es parte del código:

```
try {
 DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) recipe.tblrecipe.getModel();
 String[] datos = new String[5];
 int fil = tblinsumos.getSelectedRow();

 if (fil == -1) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO HAS SELECCIONADO NINGUN INSUMO", "ADVERTENCIA", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
 } else {
  String generico = tblinsumos.getValueAt(fil, 1).toString();
  String comercial = tblinsumos.getValueAt(fil, 2).toString();
  String formafarma = tblinsumos.getValueAt(fil, 3).toString();
  String concentracion = tblinsumos.getValueAt(fil, 4).toString();
  String dosis = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("POR FAVOR INGRESA LA CANTIDAD A DISPENSAR");

  if (dosis.equals("") || dosis.equals("0")) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "LA CANTIDAD DEBE SER \n SUPERIOR A 0", "ADVERTENCIA", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  } else {
   modelo = (DefaultTableModel) recipe.tblrecipe.getModel();
   String filaelemento[] = {
    generico,
    comercial,
    formafarma,
    concentracion,
    dosis
   };
   modelo.addRow(filaelemento);
  }
 }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es llenar los `String` que ya tienes en una lista asi:

```
 List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
 lista.add(generico);
 lista.add(comercial);
```

Entonces para llenar la otra `jTable`, la variable columnas puede ser otra lista que tengas definida

```
TableModel tablaModelo = new DefaultTableModel(lista, columnas);
JTable table = new JTable(tablaModelo );
```